# cannot build qtwebengine for raspberry pi 2 from qt5.6 source

Tags: qt, build, raspberry-pi2, qtwebengine

I am trying to compile qtwebengine for raspberry pi using
[http://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS ](link url)

AND

compilation terminates with following errors :

```
...
...
.obj/qquickwebengineview.o:qquickwebengineview.cpp:function QQuickWebEngineView::webChannel(): error: undefined reference to 'QQmlWebChannel::QQmlWebChannel(QObject*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../lib/libQt5WebEngine.so.5.6.1] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gesar/pi-qt5.6/raspi/qtwebengine/src/webengine'
make[1]: *** [sub-webengine-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gesar/pi-qt5.6/raspi/qtwebengine/src'
make: *** [sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2
```

--
What am I missing? It says about qtwebchannel but I have successfully installed qtwebchannel.

Please help. I have been trying for more than 2 weeks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by rebuilding the QtWebChannel:

```
~/raspi/qtwebchannel$ make
```

and then going back to the QtWebEngine:

```
~/raspi/qtwebengine$ make
```

This builds the libQt5WebEngine.so

Comment: Forgot to mention to copy  ~/raspi/qtwebchannel/lib/libQt5WebChannel.so.5.6.2 to :
    ~/raspi/qt5pi/lib and then do a make clean, make in each of the above directories mentioned above.